# Migration notes in schema at Data.SE

Tags: support, migration, data-explorer

I can't see subj anywhere. E.g. [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36025884/how-to-extract-reviewers-ratings-from-yelp) [doesn't have anything unusual in its `Posts` entry](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/revision/504158/638244/). Neither is there any entity in the schema with "migration" in its name.

Specifically, I'm interested in all questions migrated from SO to OpenSource.SE and Programmers.SE to find a specific one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to inspect the [`posthistory`](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2678) table for that, specially the rows for posthistorytypeid's 35 (away) and 36 (here), the comment field on those rows hold the original url

Your [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/504215) would look like this:

```
select postid as [Post Link]
     , creationdate
     , posthistorytypeid
     , case 
       when posthistorytypeid = 35 then 'Migrated Away'
       when posthistorytypeid = 36 then 'Migrated Here'
       end
     , comment     
from posthistory 
where postid = 36025884
```

which results in:

[image]

Keep in mind that post stubs will be deleted over time (60 days IIRC) so you won't find the migration history of all posts.